# Partial Derivative of Poisson CDF

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I am trying to figure out how to take the partial derivative of the Poisson CDF $F(k, \lambda)$ with respect to $k$. I have seen the partial derivative taken with respect to $\lambda$, but am unsure how to do it with respect to $k$. Especially since there is a factorial involved.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks,
Erich

Comment: If you use the notation $F(i,\lambda)$ the Poisson cdf is $e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^i \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$  So you want to differentiate with respect to the upper bound on the sum?  However, your comment at the end sounds like you are thinking of the cdf as $e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{\lambda^i}{i!},$ and you want to differentiate with respect to the index.  Which is it?

Comment: Could you mention what you're doing that requires you to differentiate with respect to that parameter?

Comment: Hi. I think what I want is the upper-bound.

Comment: I'm wanting to show the anti-monotonic nature of the function with respect to $k$.

Comment: I'm still confused at what you want.  The cdf of any probability distribution is non-decreasing and thus is monotonic.  The cdf of a discrete distribution like the Poisson, though, is not strictly monotonic.

Comment: Sorry, this is so confusing, I'm probably not explaining myself clearly. I'm not in the mathematics field. So, I've seen a paper that shows the partial derivative of F(k, $\lambda$) with respect to $\lambda$, and their conclusion was that as $\lambda$ increases and $k$ is held constant, F decreases. I want to do the same but for the $k$. That is, I want to show that as $k$ increases and $\lambda$ is held constant, F decreases.

Comment: OK. I think I was being stupid with this one. As $k$ increases, of course the CDF will increase as well, by the very definition of what a CDF is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above:

QUOTE: Sorry, this is so confusing, I'm probably not explaining myself clearly. I'm not in the mathematics field. So, I've seen a paper that shows the partial derivative of $F(k, λ)$ with respect to $λ$, and their conclusion was that as $λ$ increases and $k$ is held constant, $F$ decreases. I want to do the same but for the $k$. END OF QUOTE

Since $k$ takes on only the values $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and does not vary *continuously*, the thing to do here is to use finite differences rather than derivatives.  I.e. instead of asking how fast the function is changing as $k$ varies, ask how much the function changes as $k$ increases by $1$.

So you have
$$
\begin{align}
& {} \qquad \frac{\lambda^{k+1}e^{-\lambda}}{(k+1)!} - \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} = e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k\left(\frac{\lambda}{(k+1)!} - \frac{1}{k!}\right) \\  \\
& = e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k\left(\frac{\lambda}{(k+1)!} - \frac{k+1}{(k+1)!}\right) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k}{(k+1)!}(\lambda-k-1).
\end{align}
$$
This is positive when $k<\lambda -1$ and negative when $k>\lambda-1$, and if $\lambda$ happens to be an integer, it is $0$ when $k=\lambda-1$.

Therefore the function increases on $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots,\lfloor\lambda-1\rfloor\}$ and decreases on $\{\lfloor\lambda-1\rfloor+1,\lfloor\lambda-1\rfloor+2,\lfloor\lambda-1\rfloor+3,\ldots\}$.

You might still need to look at the question of which of two values is bigger.  In that one isolated case of an exact ineger value, the maximum is attained at each of two consecutive integers.

Comment: After posting this I notice that it said "CDF", the cumulative distribution function, not the probability mass function.  That actually makes things simpler: the differences between consecutive values of the CDF are precisely the values of the probability mass function, i.e. the "derivative" is $e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{k+1}/(k+1)!$.

Answer (score 0):

This might be as good an occasion as any to recall that the whole family of Poisson distributions can be **coupled** in such a way that the distribution of each $X_\lambda$ is Poisson$(\lambda)$ and the random function $\lambda\mapsto X_\lambda$ is almost surely nondecreasing.

Consequences are that $\mathrm P(X_\lambda\geqslant x)$ for every positive $x$ and $\mathrm E(X_\lambda)$ are increasing functions of $\lambda$. More generally, $\mathrm E(u(X_\lambda))$ is a nondecreasing function of $\lambda$, for every nondecreasing function $u$.